# Adding Two Lists of Same Size at Compile-time

Tags: scala, dependent-type, idris

In Idris, I can add two vectors of the same size via:

```
module MatrixMath

import Data.Vect

addHelper : (Num n) => Vect k n -> Vect k n -> Vect k n
addHelper = zipWith (+)
```

After compiling it on the REPL:

```
*MatrixMath> :l MatrixMath.idr 
Type checking ./MatrixMath.idr
```

I can then call it with two vectors of size 3:

```
*MatrixMath> addHelper [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[5, 7, 9] : Vect 3 Integer
```

But, it will fail to compile when I try to call `addHelper` on two vectors of different size:

```
*MatrixMath> addHelper [1,2,3] [1]
(input):1:20:When checking argument xs to constructor Data.Vect.:::
        Type mismatch between
                Vect 0 a (Type of [])
        and
                Vect 2 n (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        0
                and
                        2
```

How can I write this in Scala?

Comment: Maybe [`ListOf` from this page](http://cogita-et-visa.blogspot.com/2014/05/dependent-types-in-scala.html) could be a good starting point?

Answer (score 7):

For this kind of problem, [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is very often the right thing to turn to.
Shapeless already has type-level numbers (`shapless.Nat`) and an abstraction for a collection with a compile-time known size (`shapeless.Sized`).

A first take at an implementation could look something like this

```
import shapeless.{ Sized, Nat }
import shapeless.ops.nat.ToInt
import shapeless.syntax.sized._

def Vect[A](n: Nat)(xs: A*)(implicit toInt : ToInt[n.N]) =
  xs.toVector.sized(n).get

def add[A, N <: Nat](left: Sized[Vector[A], N], right: Sized[Vector[A], N])(implicit A: Numeric[A]) =
  Sized.wrap[Vector[A], N]((left, right).zipped.map(A.plus))
```

And its usage:

```
scala> add(Vect(3)(1, 2, 3), Vect(3)(4, 5, 6))
res0: shapeless.Sized[Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = Vector(5, 7, 9)

scala> add(Vect(3)(1, 2, 3), Vect(1)(1))
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
  // long and misleading error message about variance
  // but at least it failed to compile
```

While this looks like it works, it a serious downside – you have to make sure that the provided length and the number of arguments match, otherwise you'll get a runtime error.

```
scala> Vect(1)(1, 2, 3)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
  at .Vect(<console>:27)
  ... 33 elided
```

We can do better than this. You can use `Sized` directly instead of another constructor.
Also, if we define `add` with two parameter lists, we can get a better error message (It's not as nice as what Idris offers, but it's usable):

```
import shapeless.{ Sized, Nat }

def add[A, N <: Nat](left: Sized[IndexedSeq[A], N])(right: Sized[IndexedSeq[A], N])(implicit A: Numeric[A]) =
  Sized.wrap[IndexedSeq[A], N]((left, right).zipped.map(A.plus))

// ...

add(Sized(1, 2, 3))(Sized(4, 5, 6))
res0: shapeless.Sized[IndexedSeq[Int],shapeless.nat._3] = Vector(5, 7, 9)

scala> add(Sized(1, 2, 3))(Sized(1))
<console>:24: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [CC[_]]shapeless.Sized[CC[Int],shapeless.nat._1]
    (which expands to)  [CC[_]]shapeless.Sized[CC[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]
 required: shapeless.Sized[IndexedSeq[Int],shapeless.nat._3]
    (which expands to)  shapeless.Sized[IndexedSeq[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
       add(Sized(1, 2, 3))(Sized(1))
```

But we can go further. Shapeless also offers a conversion between tuples and `Sized`, so we could write:

```
import shapeless.{ Sized, Nat }
import shapeless.ops.tuple.ToSized

def Vect[A, P <: Product](xs: P)(implicit toSized: ToSized[P, Vector]) =
  toSized(xs)

def add[A, N <: Nat](left: Sized[Vector[A], N], right: Sized[Vector[A], N])(implicit A: Numeric[A]) =
  Sized.wrap[Vector[A], N]((left, right).zipped.map(A.plus))
```

And this works, the size is inferred from the provided tuple:

```
scala> add(Vect(1, 2, 3), Vect(4, 5, 6))
res0: shapeless.Sized[Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = Vector(5, 7, 9)

scala> add(Vect(1, 2, 3))(Vect(1))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.Sized[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]]
 required: shapeless.Sized[Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
       add(Vect(1, 2, 3))(Vect(4, 5, 6, 7))
```

Unfortunately, the syntax from the example only works due to a feature called argument adaption, where scalac would automatically convert the multiple arguments from `Vect` into the tuple we needed. As this "feature" can also lead to very nasty bugs, I find myself disabling it almost always with `-Yno-adapted-args`. Using this flag, we have to explicitly write the tuple ourselves:

```
scala> Vect(1, 2, 3)
<console>:26: warning: No automatic adaptation here: use explicit parentheses.
        signature: Vect[A, P <: Product](xs: P)(implicit toSized: shapeless.ops.tuple.ToSized[P,Vector]): toSized.Out
  given arguments: 1, 2, 3
 after adaptation: Vect((1, 2, 3): (Int, Int, Int))
       Vect(1, 2, 3)
           ^
<console>:26: error: too many arguments for method Vect: (xs: (Int, Int, Int))(implicit toSized: shapeless.ops.tuple.ToSized[(Int, Int, Int),Vector])toSized.Out
       Vect(1, 2, 3)
           ^

scala> Vect((1, 2, 3))
res1: shapeless.Sized[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> add(Vect((1, 2, 3)))(Vect((4, 5, 6)))
res2: shapeless.Sized[Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = Vector(5, 7, 9)
```

Also, we could only use length up to 22, scala has no support for larger tuples.

```
scala> Vect((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23))
<console>:26: error: object <none> is not a member of package scala
       Vect((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23))
```

So, can we get the slightly nicer syntax? Turns out, we can. Shapeless can do the wrapping for us, using an HList instead:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToSized
import shapeless.{ ProductArgs, HList, Nat, Sized }

object Vect extends ProductArgs {
  def applyProduct[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit toSized: ToSized[L, Vector]) =
    toSized(l)
}

def add[A, N <: Nat](left: Sized[Vector[A], N])(right: Sized[Vector[A], N])(implicit A: Numeric[A]) =
  Sized.wrap[Vector[A], N]((left, right).zipped.map(A.plus))
```

And it works:

```
scala> add(Vect(1, 2, 3))(Vect(4, 5, 6))
res0: shapeless.Sized[Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = Vector(5, 7, 9)

scala> add(Vect(1, 2, 3))(Vect(1))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.Sized[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]
 required: shapeless.Sized[Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
       add(Vect(1, 2, 3))(Vect(1))
                              ^

scala> Vect(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
res2: shapeless.Sized[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[... long type elided... ]]] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
```

You could go further from there, wrapping the `Sized` in your own class for example

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToSized
import shapeless.{ ProductArgs, HList, Nat, Sized }

object Vect extends ProductArgs {
  def applyProduct[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit toSized: ToSized[L, Vector]): Vect[toSized.Lub, toSized.N] =
    new Vect(toSized(l))
}

class Vect[A, N <: Nat] private (val self: Sized[Vector[A], N]) extends Proxy.Typed[Sized[Vector[A], N]] {
  def add(other: Vect[A, N])(implicit A: Numeric[A]): Vect[A, N] =
    new Vect(Sized.wrap[Vector[A], N]((self, other.self).zipped.map(A.plus)))
}

// ...

scala> Vect(1, 2, 3) add Vect(4, 5, 6)
res0: Vect[Int,shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = Vector(5, 7, 9)

scala> Vect(1, 2, 3) add Vect(1)
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Vect[Int,shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]
 required: Vect[Int,shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
       Vect(1, 2, 3) add Vect(1)
```

Essentially, all boils down to using `Sized` and `Nat` for the type constraints.

Answer (score 4):

[Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) can you help you in that:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.sized._

def row(cols : Seq[String]) = cols.mkString("\"", "\", \"", "\"")

def csv[N <: Nat](hdrs : Sized[Seq[String], N], rows : List[Sized[Seq[String], N]]) =
    row(hdrs) :: rows.map(row(_))

val hdrs = Sized("Title", "Author") // Sized[IndexedSeq[String], _2]
val rows = List(                  // List[Sized[IndexedSeq[String], _2]]
  Sized("Types and Programming Languages", "Benjamin Pierce"),
  Sized("The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages", "Simon Peyton-Jones")
)

 // hdrs and rows statically known to have the same number of columns
val formatted = csv(hdrs, rows)
```

Note how the method `csv` constraints both `Sized` by `N <: Nat`, the same way in you example that you constraint by `Num n`.

I copied this code from Shapeless [examples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sized.scala), if it doesn't compile the way it is I might very well have missed something.